# Ruby on Rails keep checkbox checked after form submitted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an app in Rails where you can select from different categories of what you want displayed, and I am using a form and checkboxes to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get the checkboxes to stay checked after rendering the page.  My controller:

```
def select
@grants = Array.new
@cat = Array.new

@has = params[:select]

@has.each do |key, value|
  if value != 'no'
    @cat.push(value)
  end
end

  if @cat != nil
  @cat.each do |cat|
    @grants = @grants.concat(sortbycategory(Grant.all, cat))
  end
  if params[:obprice] == 'yes'
    arrangebyprice(@grants)
  elsif params[:obdate] == 'yes'
    arrangebydate(@grants)
  end
  @grants = Kaminari.paginate_array(@grants).page(params[:page]).per(25)
  render :partial => 'select', :layout => 'application'
else
  puts 'something went wrong'
end
end
```

And this is one of the checkboxes I am using in the view.

```
<form action="/allgrant/select" method="post">
  <% unless are_grants?("agriculture") == false %>
 <li>
<p id = 'shifter'>
 <input name="select[agriculture]" type="hidden" value="no" />
 <label>

 <input type="checkbox" name = "select[agriculture]" value = 'agriculture'/>
 Agriculture

</label>
 </p>
 </li>
<br>
```

I found this javascript and tried using and tinkering with it, but it selects all checkboxes or none when I use it

```
 <script>
 $(function(){
  var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
  $('input').prop('checked', test);
  });

   $('input').on('change', function() {
  localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
   });
   </script>
```

I'll put my code from the comment here as well, becuase its not showing up right

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "select[agriculture]" value = 'agriculture' <%= @cat.include? 'agriculture' ? "checked=checked" : "" %> />
```

Comment: Should the checkbox be checked by default? In this case you can do `checked: 'checked'` on the input

Comment: No, I don't want all of them checked just the ones that they selected so they can see what they picked.  And I did try doing that and it was still unchecked when I submitted the form

Comment: Just a quick thought. Actually, you're using two inputs with the name `select[agriculture]` (one hidden and other a checkbox). And to check/uncheck checkboxes you'll have to manage someway the `checked` attribute.

Comment: The hidden value is there for when the box is unchecked it passes in 'no' rather than passing in nothing at all.  It checks and unchecks when clicked and passes in the correct string, I just can't get it to stay checked once the page is rendered, does the check attribute have anything that would control that aspect?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to put some logic in the view, like `<input type="checkbox" name = "select[agriculture]" value = 'agriculture' <%= (model.field != "no") ? "checked=checked" : "" %> />`.

Comment: model.field gives me an error, but I get what you're saying.  I tried saving my @cat variable to a session variable and then in the view using                 <input type="checkbox" name = "select[agriculture]" value = 'agriculture' <%= @cat.include? 'agriculture' ? "checked=checked" : "" %> /> but that didn't quite do it

Comment: Yes, it was just an example. You must pass the actual db value of the field to the view, so html can know it's value. Normally it's via @session variable or partial/locals.

Comment: Actually that just worked, I forgot the parenthesis around the @cat.include statement.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: But i'm sure thats the way. Maybe some `Rails.logger.debug` can help.

Comment: @John you're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here:

```
  var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
  $('input').prop('checked', test);
```

is why all the checkboxes are being checked.

You have a global variable stored at `localStorage.input`.

When you call `$('input').prop('checked', test)` that is selecting *all inputs* and applying the property.

Storing the state in `localStorage` seems like a sensible approach, but you'd need to store the state for each checkbox individually and would need to apply the properties to each checkbox on an individual basis.

In the following example, each checkbox input's HTML markup is expected to have an id attribute which is a unique identifier:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").forEach(function(node){
  var $input   = $(node),
      selector = $input.attr("id")
  if (localStorage[selector]) {
    $("#" + selector ).prop("checked", true)
  }
})

$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(e) {
  var $input    = $(e.currentTarget),
      selector  = $input.attr("id"),
      isChecked = $input.is(':checked') === 'true'
      nextState = !isChecked
  localStorage[selector] = nextState
  console.log($input.attr("id") + " is checked? " + nextState)
});
```